# microsoft mouse and keyboard center doesn't show my mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse

as part of a recent windows update, the irritating and intrusive intellipoint microsoft mouse software  now seems to have been replaced by the even more irritating and intrusive "microsoft mouse and keyboard center[sic]"

I am left handed and need to switch the left and right mouse buttons round. the option to do this has disappeared from the mouse control panel, to be replaced by a link which opens up said mouse and keyboard center. this in turn is a window which allows me to change settings on the keyboard but does not have any way to control mouse settings

any hints would be very welcome. this is driving me nuts.

Comment: FWIW, my mouse is supported but switching the software to a left-handed configuration (which involves reprogramming the two buttons, not just checking an "I'm left handed" or "Swap buttons" checkbox) doesn't actually seem to do anything - my mouse still acts right handed. It's not even bloatware that works, which is even more irritating...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ensure your mouse is on Microsoft's [Mouse and Keyboard Center compatibility list](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/help/windows-8/troubleshooting/mouse/supported-devices):

> Some older Microsoft devices are no longer supported in Microsoft
>   Mouse and Keyboard Center; however they are still supported by the
>   IntelliPoint 8.2/IntelliType Pro 8.2 software.
>
> If you have installed the Mouse and Keyboard Center software and are
>   unable to locate and configure your device, check the following lists
>   of devices to confirm which software supports your device. The name of
>   your device is displayed on the underside.
>
> If your device is not supported by Mouse and Keyboard Center software,
>   use the Control Panel to uninstall it, and then reinstall the
>   IntelliPoint/IntelliType Pro software.

The following table shows which Microsoft mice are supported in Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center (v1.1):

- Basic Optical Mouse  Yes
- Basic Optical Mouse v2.0 Yes
- Comfort Optical Mouse 3000   Yes
- Compact Optical Mouse 500 v2.0   Yes
- IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0    Yes
- Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 6000    Yes
- Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 7000    Yes
- Notebook Optical Mouse 3000  Yes
- SideWinder Mouse Yes
- Trackball Explorer   Yes
- Trackball Optical    Yes
- Wheel Mouse Optical  Yes
- Wireless Laser Mouse 5000    Yes
- Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 v2.0   Yes
- Wireless Laser Mouse 7000    Yes
- Wireless Laser Mouse 8000    Yes
- Wireless Notebook Optical Mouse 4000 Yes
- Wireless Notebook Presenter Mouse 8000   Yes
- Wireless Optical Mouse 2.0   Yes
- Wireless Optical Mouse 2000  Yes
- Wireless Optical Mouse 5000  Yes
- SideWinder X5 Mouse  Yes
- Wireless Mobile Mouse 3000   Yes
- Explorer Mouse   Yes
- Explorer Mini Mouse  Yes
- SideWinder X8 Mouse  Yes
- Arc Mouse    Yes
- SideWinder X3 Mouse  Yes
- Wireless Mobile Mouse 6000   Yes
- Wireless Mobile Mouse 4000   Yes
- Wireless Mouse 5000  Yes
- Wireless Mouse 2000  Yes
- Comfort Mouse 4500   Yes
- Wireless Mobile Mouse 3500   Yes
- Arc Touch Mouse  Yes
- Wireless Mobile Mouse 1000   Yes
- Wireless Mobile Mouse 3000 v2.0  Yes
- Wireless Mouse 1000  Yes
- Touch Mouse  Yes
- Express Mouse    Yes
- Comfort Mouse 3000   Yes
- Comfort Mouse 6000   Yes
- Explorer Touch Mouse Yes
- Comfort Optical Mouse 1000   No
- Compact Optical Mouse    No
- IntelliMouse Explorer 4.0    No
- IntelliMouse Explorer for Bluetooth  No
- Laser Mouse 6000 No
- Notebook Optical Mouse   No
- Optical Mouse    No
- Optical Mouse by Starck  No
- Standard Wireless Optical Mouse  No
- Wireless IntelliMouse Explorer for Bluetooth No
- Wireless Notebook Laser Mouse 6000   No
- Wireless Notebook Laser Mouse 7000   No
- Wireless Notebook Optical Mouse  No
- IntelliMouse No
- Wireless Notebook Optical Mouse 3000 No
- IntelliMouse Optical No
- Mobile Memory Mouse 8000 No
- Wireless Laser Mouse 6000    No
- Wireless IntelliMouse Explorer 2.0   No
- Wireless IntelliMouse Explorer with Fingerprint Reader   No
- Wheel Mouse  No

Comment: Thanks, my mouse is not on the supported list so I'll just uninstall the software. <rant>It seems pretty stupid that the control center installed itself and disabled the other software when it doesn't even support my mouse <bigger rant>generally i hate it when third party hardware manufacturers provide bloatware drivers when the built in windows facilities are perfectly good enough; when microsoft themselves do it i'm baffled as well as angry </bigger rant></rant>

Comment: The crappiest thing about Microsoft's hardware - is its software. I don't know why the insist on building such rubbish resource hogs.

Comment: I know it is old question but don't want to set another one. I have Sidewinder X5. I haven't any problems with it to this time but now Mouse and Keyboard center 2.8 does not detect it. It is on support list, I saw it before in Mouse center but now when I reinstalled my Windows I cant configure it because it is not detected. In devmgmt.msc there is show as HID-compliant device. Does anybody have any idea?